# How to return no duplicates for records that have many-to-many values

Tags: google-bigquery, duplicates

I am trying to find the correct join construction to join together the relevant customer info from the Rentals table with the Accidents table. I often run into this issue where my joining fields aren't unique but not sure what else to join on. The accidents table only has about 1500 records but when I join it to pull in more customer data, I get like 35k records. I can do some joins but frequently have joins like this at work and I feel like a dummy because I am not sure how to troubleshoot...

```
SELECT a.*,
r.market,
r.date_of_birth,
r.is_blocked,
r.rate_type
FROM `accidents` a
LEFT JOIN `rentals` r -- I also tried an INNER JOIN
USING (customer_id) -- Other fields I tried to match on: Full Name 
ORDER BY accident_dt DESC
```

Comment: You are missing `ON` in your `JOIN` clause. This will be used to define the relationship of the two tables. Which column in rentals table refers to the accidents table?

Comment: Your final data set should be :(a) a record for every customer, (b) every accident, (c) someting different. For b): A dirty solution is `select a.name,a.address,a.phone, any_value(r.rate) from (  ) group by 1,2,3 ` and write inside the brackets your code.